# SATA controller installed but not working? (No drives show up/Don't see card's BIOS)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bios, sata

I have an old Promise FastTrak S150 TX4 SATA controller card.  I put it in an old machine running Windows Server 2003.  I booted the machine.  The new hardware was detected.  I installed the drivers.

So now in Device Manager under "SCSI and RAID Controllers" I see "Win Server 2003 Promise FastTrak S150 TX4 Controller" and "Win Server 2003 Promise RAID Console SCSI Processor Device"

I previously had the card in a machine that is now dead.  When I booted that machine, during the boot process I would see the card info displayed and the drives that were attached.  Boot would finish and my drives would be available.

When I boot this new machine I never see that screen/text.  No hard drives are available/visible.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

EDIT:  I had never opened this machine before.  When I opened it I saw that it's only hard drive was connected via PATA, so I figured it didn't have onboard SATA.  But upon closer look, lo and behold, there are two open SATA ports on the motherboard.  I plugged the hard drive into that and it works.

However, I guess my question now is, is it possible to get the additional controller card working too?  I played around in the BIOS and never saw anything about enabling an addon card.  I did find a setting enabling SATA, but I assume this just refers to the onboard SATA.

Comment: perhaps the card is dead?  Or, try removing other cards in the box until the bios msg shows up?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable something in the BIOS - look for something like `Show Add In Card Boot Screens` or `Enable Add In Card Boot Screens` or similar.